# Integrate n2cms to static html site

Tags: n2cms

I would like to start n2Cms. there were lots of samples available. but i could not understand any. 
my requirement is

1) am having the html static site, so need to add cms feature to it

2) the site is not MVC.

if any know how to do this, please help me with step by step by guide

Answer (score 0):

N2CMS doesn't have a feature to import a static HTML site. Currently, the only way to do what you are asking is create a new site based on N2, set up the template using WebForms or ASP.NET MVC, and then copy/paste your existing content into N2CMS.

Setup instructions for N2CMS are here: https://n2cmsdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/N2CMS/Setting+Up+Your+Environment